# Webview not loading

Tags: android, android-webview

I have webview in one of my activity which should be loaded within a portion in that page and not like opening up browser. So I have used web view client for that.

The url is opening up in mobile browser and also in my chrome. But its always showing up "Webpage not available" when I run in app. Normal "http://www.google.com" is working. My URL is .asp file and contains http as prefix too. I don't understand why its causing this issue. I googled a lot but not able to solve.

My app version is Android 14. I have internet permission too in manifest.

My code snippet is as follows:

```
public static void loadWebView(WebView wView, String url) {
    wView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    wView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    wView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    wView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(false);
    wView.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");
    wView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    wView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    wView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    wView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    MyClient wbClient = new MyClient();
    wView.setWebViewClient(wbClient);
    if(url.endsWith(".pdf") || url.endsWith(".PDF")) {
        url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url;
    }

    url.replace("http:", "https:");
    wView.loadUrl(url);
}

private static class MyClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to get the url in logcat ending with .asp, it may not have www check it

Comment: @Arju it has www in the URL

Comment: can you post the url that you are trying to load

Comment: Sorry @Arju, since its client specific URL I can't post it. But I found one issue. My URL contains &…So the text is cutting off from the URL itself when I do SAX Parsing. I need to check that first then...

Comment: Yeah, thats ok, Proceed with your findings :)

Comment: @Arju URL issue is fixed and web view is loading now…No issues.. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
url.replace("http:", "https:");
```

This line could the problem.

Well I run your code in my environment it works:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView v = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    loadWebView(v,"http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx");
}
```

Try to call loadWebView() as above.
And double check if you have really the permission in the manifest file, as follows

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Hope it helps.